# Join files in the single bundle file but avoiding emit Commonjs file in bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I have some `*.ts` files which I want to join in a single `bundle.js` file. To do that I'm using `webpack version 3.*`. The problem is that I want to avoid importing other libraries or Commonjs emitting in bundle file. For example I have `import * as firebase from 'firebase` will be emitted in bundle file which I want to avoid it. Only the file I wrote should be joined such as file1.ts, file2.ts, ... .